# Angular 2 Pass parameter to a validator function

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an array in my formcomponent class and want to be able to pass that array to a validator function. When adding multiple validators to the form, I am using Validators.compose function. This only accepts the name of the validator function though, and not any parameters to pass. Is it possible to add parameters to the function calls inside of the "compose" function?

```js
export class ClientFormComponent
{
    clientForm: ControlGroup;
    npi: AbstractControl;
    name: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private _clientService: ClientService, _fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.clientForm = _fb.group({ 'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 'npi': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, npiNumValidator, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)])]});
        this.name = this.clientForm.controls['name'];
        this.npi = this.clientForm.controls['npi'];
    }
    
    @Input() clientList;
    active = true;   
   
    onSubmit(value: Client) {
        this._clientService.addDeleteClient(value, true)
            .subscribe(
            client => this.clientList.push(client));        
    }    
}

function npiNumValidator(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (isNaN(control.value)) {
        return { npiNAN: true };
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just move it to a class

```
class NpiNumValicator {
  constructor(private someField: someType) {}

  npiNumValidator(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (isNaN(control.value)) {
        return { npiNAN: true };
    }
  }
}
```

then use it like

```
this.clientForm = _fb.group({ 'name': ['',
    Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 'npi': ['', 
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
        new NpiNumValidator(someArg).npiNumValidator, 
        Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)
    ])
]});
```

to be able to use `this` within `npiNumValidator` you can use

```
var npiNumVal = new NpiNumValidator(someArg);
this.clientForm = _fb.group({ 'name': ['',
    Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 'npi': ['', 
    Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
        npiNumVal.npiNumValidator.bind(npiNumVal), 
        Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)
    ])
]});
```

Comment: When I use this method on RC4. When the validator function is called, 'this' is undefined

Comment: Same issue as Droxx - Angular 2.4.0, and trying to include in-class properties in a validator function. 'this' is undefined

Comment: @Droxx sorry, I missed your comment.

Comment: I followed the example but got the error 'Uncaught(in promise): TypeError xxx is not a constructor'. I think that is because of new instance of typescript class. Not sure the right order for the validation.

Comment: @Bigeyes sorry, but that's not emough information. I'd suggest to create a new question with full information.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it possible to add parameters to the function calls inside of the
>   "compose" function?

**Validator Declaration:** [straight out of Angular Code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/common/src/forms/validators.ts)

```ts
/* Validator that requires controls to have a value of a minimum length. */

static minLength(minLength: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: modelModule.AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      if (isPresent(Validators.required(control))) return null;
      var v: string = control.value;
      return v.length < minLength ?
                 {"minlength": {"requiredLength": minLength, "actualLength": v.length}} :
                 null;
    };
  }
```

**Usage:**

```ts
Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4)]
```

---

***NOTE: to understand it better, see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)***

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: I love your answer! If I could I would vote twice for it! thanks

Answer (score 4):

You also leverage a method of your component to create the validation function. This way you will be able to access properties of this component using an arrow function.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fieldName: [ '', this.createValidator() ]
    });
  }

  createValidator() {
    return (control) =>  {
      var arr = this.arr;
      (...)
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: how could i call this fn inside a template driven form

Answer (score 4):

In some cases the data that needs to be passed to the validator is dynamic and can be found in the class that is calling the validator.  In those instances I just have simply used "bind(this)" when adding the validator.
Here is a formBuilder example:

```
this.profileFormGroups.push( this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [profile.name,
            Validators.compose([
              Validators.required,
              Validators.maxLength(30),
              Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')
              ]),
            this.myNameValidator.bind(this)
          ]
  }) );
}, this);
```

Then in your validator just reference the dynamic parameter:

//my Async Validator

```
myNameValidator(control: FormControl): any {
  let vm = this;

  return new Promise(resolve => {
   if ( vm.mydynamicvalue === control.name ) { ... }
      resolve({"Invalid User":true});
   else
      resolve(null)
  });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reference dynamic data from the class you can pass an object within the parameter instead of a primitive.

Example:

```
  valParams = {
    gte: 10
  }
  constructor(protected _fb:FormBuilder) { 
    this.numForm = _fb.group({
      num: ['', gte(this.valParams)]
    });
  }
```

Validation Function:

```
export function gte(valParams: {gte:number}): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let val: number = +control.value;
 
    if (isNaN(val)) return { 'gte': true }   
    if (val <= +valParams.gte) return { 'gte': true }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Since you're passing an object JavaScript will reference the object in memory rather than an immutable primitive.

PS: As a bonus since you're passing the object reference, you can update the object directly from the validation function which can then be read by the component class.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer meant I will have to create a class for each validator which I didn't like. Here is my approach:

```
public static npiNumValidator(
    x: any
  ): (AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors | null {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return !!x ? null : { error: true};
    };
}
```

Use as:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   email: [undefined, [ClassName.npiNumValidator('value')]],
});
```